# Java REST API POST return Future

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post, completable-future

In one of my projects I want to develop Asynchronous REST API in Spring Boot (1.5.8) with POST because the code executed by the API is very long.

First question is: Does it make sense to return a `CallableFuture` from a POST request?
If so how to block the client until the effective response comes?

Here it is the code of my REST API:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CompletableFuture<String> postAPI(@RequestBody() String param) { 
LOGGER.info("I received a POST request");
CompletableFuture<String> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(function(param));
return result;}
```

And following is the code I'm using to call it and retrieve the result.

```
ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> response = restTemplate
    .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
        String.class);
ResponseEntity<String> result = response.get();
String response = result.getBody();
```

The `response.get()` doesn't actually block the execution, so the `getBody()` always returns null.

Comment: No.  The response should immediately return with a response indicating the long running task has started - even just an HTTP OK.  If the client needs to know the result of the task then the initial response could include something like a transaction ID associated with the task.  The client then occasionally (ever few seconds or so) calls another endpoint with that transaction ID which checks to see if the task completed (or had an error), and returns the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you missed a major point that communication between client and server over HTTP is always in "Request-Response" model.

It means:

on server side - when you `return result;` - request completed.

on the client side - when you got a response this request-response communication done.

So you have two options either:

- make another request from client to get actual result for  `CompletableFuture` result you sent in first response. Of course with corresponding method on server side. Then client will wait until server returns actual result.
- Do not complete first call until server have actual result. This seems like it is not what you want to do, but...
  If you want to block client- what is actual reason to send immediate `CompletableFuture` response at all?

There is only one reason to do such things from client side is **to do not block client** while server processes a request.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that CompletableFuture already had some kind of polling mechanism